# (0xc0210000) Error while trying to Connect PostgreSQL via C++

Tags: c++, postgresql

**Background**

I'm trying to establish a basic connection to a Postgresql Database via C++. For that i'm using Visual Studio 2019.
I'm following the instructions that can be found in http://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_c_cpp.htm

The paths to the additional libpqxx and PostgreSQL includes, libraries and dependencies have all been added: [Includes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMzF1.jpg), [Libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAfku.jpg), [Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Vesu.jpg).

I'm trying to connect to a Database "test" at port 5433.

```cpp
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <pqxx/pqxx>
    
    using namespace std;
    using namespace pqxx;
    
    int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        try {
            connection C("dbname = test user = postgres password = 1234 hostaddr = localhost port = 5433");
            if (C.is_open()) {
                cout << "Opened database successfully: " << C.dbname() << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << "Can't open database" << endl;
                return 1;
            }
            //C.disconnect();
        }
        catch (const std::exception & e) {
            cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

**Problem**

Building in Debug mode (x64) works without problem:

```
Rebuild started...
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: TEST_IT002, Configuration:
Debug x64 ------
1>TEST_IT002.cpp
1>C:\Users\yassi\source\repos\TEST_IT002\TEST_IT002\TEST_IT002.cpp(8,26):
warning C4100: 'argv': unreferenced formal parameter
1>C:\Users\yassi\source\repos\TEST_IT002\TEST_IT002\TEST_IT002.cpp(8,14):
warning C4100: 'argc': unreferenced formal parameter
1>TEST_IT002.vcxproj ->
C:\Users\yassi\source\repos\TEST_IT002\x64\Debug\TEST_IT002.exe
1>Done building project "TEST_IT002.vcxproj".
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

But as soon as i try to run the Programm (also in Debug Mode x64), i get the following Error:

```
'TEST_IT002.exe' (Win32): Loaded
'C:\Users\yr\source\repos\TEST_IT002\x64\Debug
'TEST_IT002.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'TEST_IT002.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'.
'TEST_IT002.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'.
'TEST_IT002.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'.
'TEST_IT002.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ws2_32.dll'.
'TEST_IT002.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'.
'TEST_IT002.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp140d.dll'.
'TEST_IT002.exe' (Win32): Loaded
'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140d.dll'.
'TEST_IT002.exe' (Win32): Loaded
'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140_1d.dll'.
'TEST_IT002.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbased.dll'.
The thread 0x4e24 has exited with code -1071579136 (0xc0210000).
The thread 0x2624 has exited with code -1071579136 (0xc0210000).
The program '[8808] TEST_IT002.exe' has exited with code -1071579136
(0xc0210000).
```

I have tried to connect to the default database and I have tried different Versions of Libpqxx, Unfortunately i still get the same error message:

[image]

Any suggestion to help solve this issue is highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Notice that there is no info on libpq dll(s) getting loaded, are they installed properly and present in 'path' env variable?

Comment: I added the paths to the libpq dll in the env variables, yet still get the same error.

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint at the line where you do `is_open()` and step through line by line, to know which line throws that error. By the way, can you give english meaning of the error shown in German?

Comment: The Translation to English would be:
Application Error
The application couldn't open correctly (0xc0210000). Click "OK", to close the Application.

I've set a breakpoint and the error comes right at connection C.

Comment: Ok, that tutorial mentions libpqxx 4.0, which version you downloaded? Also, did you use `cmake` to build the libpq source code and obtained the 64-bit DLLs ?

Comment: follow the instructions in the libpqxx on [Github](https://github.com/jtv/libpqxx), since that [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_c_cpp.htm) may be outdated.

Comment: thanks! I'll try with the Github Tutorial.
I've noticed that the error comes even before the code starts. I've tried a normal hello world programm which worked perfectly fine. I think i might need yet again a new installation of libpqxx

Comment: After following the Github instructions, everything's working fine! Thank you for your help !

Comment: Good to know, I am adding as answer you could mark as accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those running into similar issue, following the latest instructions in the libpqxx [Gitub](https://github.com/jtv/libpqxx) page would solve the issue.